# How to define the behavior of a method that is called by chain dependency using Mockito and JUnit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, dependency-injection, mockito

how to mock this kind of method call where the method is being called by chain dependency?

```
happyPostsDto.setImage(post.getUser().getImage().getImageUrl());
```

So far I have tried this but didn't work out.

```
 @Mock
 HappyPost happyPost;

 @Mock
 User user;

 @Mock
 Images images;
```

and in the @Test method

```
 when(happyPost.getUser()).thenReturn(new User());
 when(user.getImage()).thenReturn(new Images());
 when(images.getImageUrl()).thenReturn("jhv");
 Assertions.assertEquals(happyPosts.size(),happyPostService.mapHappyPosts(happyPosts).size());
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Have a look at https://idodevjobs.wordpress.com/2015/04/09/mockito-deep-stubs-example/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to establish your own chain of mocked objects. I see that you're trying to return `new User()` and `new Images()`. Instead of these create your own `mockedUser` and `mockedImages`. You can do something like:

```
...
// create mocked objects of user and images
User mockedUser = Mockito.mock(User.class);
Images mockedImages = Mockito.mock(Images.class);

//now create a chain
when(mockedImages.getImageUrl()).thenReturn("jhv");
when(mockedUser.getImage()).thenReturn(mockedImages);
when(happyPost.getUser()).thenReturn(mockedUser);
...
```

As a side note: You're already mocking these:

```
 @Mock
 User user;

 @Mock
 Images images;
```

So you can use `user` as well in place of `mockedUser`. Same goes for `images` and `mockedImages`.

Comment: But I have already tried that. 

 //@Mock
 HappyPost happyPost;

 //@Mock
 User user;

 //@Mock
 Images images;

Comment: check the side note in answer